# Why does this pattern not match QUERY_STRING  in RewriteCond while it matches in preg_match?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, preg-match

Here is what I have in my `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^(run=[a-z0-9A-z]{13})$
RewriteRule %{QUERY_STRING}  \? [L]
```

All I am doing is Rewriting the `QUERY_STRING` for all `QUERY_STRING` similar to `run=4f13665700694` and do nothing. A URL example: `http://thinkingmonkey.me/runs/?run=4f13665700694`. So, the RewriteCond should Match. But the above does not work.

But, the pattern seemed correct. Since, *both [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) & [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) use [`PCRE - Perl Compatible Regular Expressions`](http://www.pcre.org/)*.

I tried it using `preg_match`.

```
$subject = "run=4f13665700694"; 
$pattern = "/^(run=[a-z0-9A-z]{13})$/";

echo preg_match($pattern, $subject);
```

And as excepted the above will output:

```
1
```

i.e. a successful match.

*I do not understand why. What am I missing here?*

Comment: By "do nothing" do you mean rewrite to `http://thinkingmonkey.me/runs/?` in this case?

Comment: @TerryE Yes. But, I resolved the problem here. `%{QUERY_STRING}` cannot be used as the pattern to be matched & replaced in `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the second line. Try changing it to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1?
```

Comment: +1 You can't use variables in the RewriteRule pattern.  And a simpler way of writing this regexp is ^(.*) as the query string is already stripped from the subject.

Comment: You forget the trailing ? on the substitution string ;-)